# Voice resonating at the back of the mouth

Tags: voice, voice-training

I have started taking singing lessons. My teacher is asking me to make my voice resonates at the back of my mouth.

My goal is to sing pop songs, so to have a way to sing that is like modern pop singers. I wonder if this technique is appropriate for this style of music? I know she sings opera, so I wonder if it’s a technique that is just for opera singers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resonance is genre independent. The only time one might not opt for maximum or at least controlled resonance is if they have commercially valuable tone already. 
Think Louis Armstrong. The techniques your teacher is going through with you will likely help you sing freely openly and easily.

However if you want to sing pop, as you get more advanced, you might want to spend time with someone who sings pop.

This is true of all instruments. The fundamentals carry across genre. Style is something that you want to learn from someone who is seasoned in the style.

Comment: Also, no opera singer I know of teaches proper microphone technique, or how to do a sound check. Unfortunately, most pop teachers don't, either, but some do, and IMO, this is an essential part of being a pop singer. How to choose a microphone that fits your voice, your style, and your usage scenarios (e.g. don't bring a condenser onto a loud stage), how to hold a microphone (you'd be surprised how many singers get this wrong), how to sing into a microphone (likewise), what is the proximity effect, how does it work, and how to use it, how to properly set up monitors (oh, how often I see that) …

Comment: how to communicate with the sound engineer / monitor engineer during sound check and during the performance, how to play with the compressor, the reverb, the delay, etc. One of the best singers I ever heard came up to me before the soundcheck and told me *exactly* which frequencies to cut and which to boost (he had them memorized for all the popular vocal microphones) and what the delay parameters should be. The whole soundcheck was done in less than 5 minutes, and it sounded amazing.